# Thruster force calculation for guided travel

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

I have a little 3D game where I control the forces I apply on a ship. I run the guidance program at regular intervals (100 times per second). I am having trouble coming up with maths to get my ship to arrive at a position with a certain velocity, all in vector form.

So far I got the current velocity of the ship, the current position, the mass, the Front, Right, Up directions using the world matrix of the ship, and the max force that can be applied on any of the axes. I also need to take into account a max speed of the ship, but that shouldn't be too difficult to do once I have a solution. I removed rotation from the calculations by just taking the least force that can be applied per direction (Front, Back, Left, Right, Up, Down).

I started by obtaining relative positions and velocities by subtracting my position from the target position, and my velocity from the target velocity. I then projected those on the 3 main directions that I got from the matrix to get the components of these relative vectors on the thrust directions. But I am lost here.

I basically need to calculate the force applied on the 6 directions (or 3, if you want to allow force to be negative, which makes more sense) to finally arrive at a position with a certain velocity (all vectors), taking into account my current position and my current velocity (also vectors) and mass, in known time steps.

Comment: Let me see if I can describe what you're looking for in mathematical terms:  you have a known initial velocity vector $\vec{v}_i$ and a known final velocity vector $\vec{v}_f$.  You also have a known initial position $\vec{r}_i$ and a known final position $\vec{r}_f$.  You want to find a trajectory $\vec{r}(t)$ that has the given endpoints and the given tangential velocities at the end.  Am I understanding this correctly, or have I missed something?

Comment: The first part is correct, but I am not sure about the second. I want to apply forces to achieve the trajectory you described.

Comment: I also have that max force constraint.

Comment: I also assume I need to calculate a force vector which I can project on the Forward, Right, Up local directions of my ship.

Comment: Once you find the trajectory $\vec{r}(t)$ you can find the acceleration $\vec{a}(t)$ along it, and thus the force $\vec{F}(t) = m \vec{a}(t)$ needed to achieve it.  In this perspective the "maximum force constraint" is just a "maximum acceleration constraint": $\vec{a}(t) = \vec{F}(t)/m$ must not exceed a certain magnitude.    My concern is that there probably isn't a unique trajectory that satisfies the criteria, so you'll either have to find some algorithm that finds a "good enough" solution (maybe not a "good" one), or define some objective function that is minimized among the trajectories.

Comment: How would such an (iterative) solution look like?

Comment: Unless you also care about fuel efficiency or have to spend nonnegligible time rotating to a new heading, burning as hard as possible at all times will always minimize travel time, so you can set the magnitude of acceleration to the maximum as a constant, if you're trying to minimize time.

Comment: I actually have thrust on 6 directions, I do not need to rotate. I've been looking for some answers, but I always arrive at equations I can't solve.